# How to edit and update the Item Status of an Order Item in an order in magento

Tags: magento

As soon an order is placed in magento, the order item has Item Status as 'Ordered'. I am able to fetch this status. But I need to edit this status,something like 'creating'.

Tried Using the code below but the changes are not reflected

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId); 
$ordered_items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($ordered_items as $item){  
      $item->getStatus();
      $item->setStatus('Creating');
      $order->save();
      }
```

Even tried with an option suggested here [Howto update order item's custom option in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687630/howto-update-order-items-custom-option-in-magento) which is also not working.
Please add your suggestions here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order item don't have a separate field - status. To understand how to determine status you can see method Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item :: getStatusId

```
/**
 * Retrieve item status identifier
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getStatusId()
{
    $backordered = (float)$this->getQtyBackordered();
    if (!$backordered && $this->getHasChildren()) {
        $backordered = (float)$this->_getQtyChildrenBackordered();
    }
    $canceled    = (float)$this->getQtyCanceled();
    $invoiced    = (float)$this->getQtyInvoiced();
    $ordered     = (float)$this->getQtyOrdered();
    $refunded    = (float)$this->getQtyRefunded();
    $shipped     = (float)$this->getQtyShipped();

    $actuallyOrdered = $ordered - $canceled - $refunded;

    if (!$invoiced && !$shipped && !$refunded && !$canceled && !$backordered) {
        return self::STATUS_PENDING;
    }
    if ($shipped && $invoiced && ($actuallyOrdered == $shipped)) {
        return self::STATUS_SHIPPED;
    }

    if ($invoiced && !$shipped && ($actuallyOrdered == $invoiced)) {
        return self::STATUS_INVOICED;
    }

    if ($backordered && ($actuallyOrdered == $backordered) ) {
        return self::STATUS_BACKORDERED;
    }

    if ($refunded && $ordered == $refunded) {
        return self::STATUS_REFUNDED;
    }

    if ($canceled && $ordered == $canceled) {
        return self::STATUS_CANCELED;
    }

    if (max($shipped, $invoiced) < $actuallyOrdered) {
        return self::STATUS_PARTIAL;
    }

    return self::STATUS_MIXED;
}
```

and available statuses:

```
/**
 * Retrieve order item statuses array
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getStatuses()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_statuses)) {
        self::$_statuses = array(
            //self::STATUS_PENDING        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pending'),
            self::STATUS_PENDING        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ordered'),
            self::STATUS_SHIPPED        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipped'),
            self::STATUS_INVOICED       => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoiced'),
            self::STATUS_BACKORDERED    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Backordered'),
            self::STATUS_RETURNED       => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Returned'),
            self::STATUS_REFUNDED       => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Refunded'),
            self::STATUS_CANCELED       => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Canceled'),
            self::STATUS_PARTIAL        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Partial'),
            self::STATUS_MIXED          => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Mixed'),
        );
    }
    return self::$_statuses;
}
```

Comment: The Order Item status dont have a data base entry.? So the order item status what we are getting shown at the magento admin is just based on the status of the order right.?

Comment: Status depends on shipped, canceled, invoiced, refunded item or not

Comment: STATUS_MIXED is confusing. Can anyone explain when items will be in mixed status.

Comment: Small addition: e.g. `$item->getStatusName($item->getStatusId())` will translate the integer to an actual name.

Comment: how to update item status to shipped pro grammatically?